# Match two lines, replace with three lines

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to use `sed` to replace *every* matching two-line pattern with a three line pattern. Here's my input file (`tempfile.txt`).

```
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
```

Basically, if a `client-hostname "HOSTNAME";`
 is missing, then it should be replaced with a `tab` and then a `newline`.

My attempt:
`sed 'N; /hardware.*}/d; P; D' tempfile.txt`

The result is:

```
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
```

This is my desired output.

```
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  <tab>
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  <tab>
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
```

So as you can see, there are consistently three lines between the curlies.  That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: I don't quite understand: "if it is missing, it should to be replaced"...? Can you show the desired output?

Comment: Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I mean, [edit] the question so it's more clear, also for future visitors, without having to dig through comments.

Comment: Done.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I have edited the question: you're actually replacing two matching lines by three lines - I've changed the wording accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin.  You are a `sed` champion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick (piping to `cat -A` to show non-printable characters):

```
$ sed -r 'N;s/^([[:space:]]*hardware.*)(\n})$/\1\n\t\2/;t;P;D' infile | cat -A
lease 192.168.6.100 {$
  binding state free;$
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;$
^I$
}$
lease 192.168.6.100 {$
  binding state active;$
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;$
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";$
}$
lease 192.168.6.100 {$
  binding state free;$
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;$
^I$
}$
lease 192.168.6.100 {$
  binding state active;$
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;$
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";$
}$
```

Instead of deleting matches, this captures the two lines supposed to surround the empty line and replaces with the newline and tab between. I've also added a few anchors for safer matching.

There is a bit of trickery involved because the pattern space contains two newlines after a substitution, but `P;D` prints only the first line and the starts a new cycle, which leads to unwanted newlines also after lines containing `client-hostname`.

Explained in more detail:

```
N       # Append next line to pattern space

# If the hostname is missing, insert a newline and a tab
s/^([[:space:]]*hardware.*)(\n})$/\1\n\t\2/

t      # If we did the substitution, jump to end (prints complete pattern space)
P      # Print first line in pattern space
D      # Delete first line in pattern space - starts new cycle
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to add another curly ...

```
sed 'N; s/hardware.*}/\t\n}/; P; D' andy
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;

}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state free;

}
lease 192.168.6.100 {
  binding state active;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:4c:68:00:96;
  client-hostname "andrew-H81M-S2PH";
}
```

Comment: Sorry tink, your answer was correct before I realized I asked my original question wrong.  Apologies!